# Do heroes recover health and fatigue at the end of each quest?

Tags: descent

Do heroes recover health at the end of each encounter or at the end of each quest (usually two encounters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Heroes do not recover health at the end of each encounter, only fatigue. Heroes do recover full health and fatigue at the end of each Quest (two encounters).**

The [rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/descent-second-ed/support/DJ01_Rulebook_ENG.pdf) regarding **Quests** (page 18):

> - Heroes keep all damage suffered during Encounter 1.
> - Heroes recover all fatigue suffered during Encounter 1.

and (page 20) **The Campaign Phase**

> 2). **Cleanup**: All heroes recover all damage and all fatigue....

Comment: Are the rules for the second edition the same?

Comment: @Tass, my mistake, linked to an expansion, not Descent JitD 2nd edition rules. Corrected.